# Temporary ASP.NET Hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting

So i found several questions on SO about ASP.NET and hosting, but none of them (as far as i could find) quite answered my question.

Basically, I'd like to be able to temporarily deploy websites I work on to a server so that I can verify that the deployment process goes okay. Essentially, I'm looking for a "trial" hosting that doesn't require a follow up purchase; *temporary* hosting.

Does anyone know of any such thing? *OR*, would I be better off just getting myself a separate computer that I "host" from home and deploy to that?

Comment: @Russ Cam that's a good idea, except i'd like to be able to have it publicly hosted and with my current PC specs, i can't manage having a VM up all the time.

Comment: Sounds like a separate machine may be the way to go then, although depending on how often you need to do this, a cheap host may be the less expensive option

Comment: @Thomas Shields - how long does the trial need to be?

Comment: @chobo2 not long at all. just long enough to deploy smoothly and iron out any issues, make sure it works the same on a public server.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://www.gearhost.com
I use them for my projects and they have free plan which is not limited in time, just resources.

https://youtu.be/rgAWMl-gccM